# You toss three coins. Is the event that there is at most one tails independent from the event that there is both a heads and tails present?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

You toss three coins. Is the event that there is at most one tails independent
from the event that there is both a heads and tails present?

I am new to probability and I have no idea what I am doing. This is what I have so far: 
(Defining my probability space):

Let $S$ be a string length 3 on alphabet {$H,T$}.

Let $A$ be an event that there is at most one tail.

Let $B$ be an event that there is both tail and head present.

After this I have no idea how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So we have to calculate the probabilities of both, and see what we get.

The probability that there is at most one tail is the probability that there are $3$ heads $=(\frac{1}{2})^3 = \frac{1}{8}$ plus the possibility of $1$ tail, which can come on any of the three flips, ($=\frac{1}{8}*3 = \frac{3}{8}$), which is $1/2$.

The probability that both a heads and a tails is present is the opposite of either all turning up heads or all turning up tails, which comes out to be $\frac{6}{8}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Now we have to calculate the probability of both the above happening i.e. both a head and tail turn up, and there is at most one tail. This is the same as saying that exactly one tail turns up. The probability of that happening is $\frac{3}{8}$.

Independence of two events $A$ and $B$ happens when $P(A)P(B)=P(A \cap B)$. In this case, $\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{3}{4}$ is equal to $\frac{3}{8}$, whence the events are independent. Please ask if any doubts.

Comment: Little confused at the very end. How did you get 1/2?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is one tail and one head, then you have equal probability to have 2 heads / 1 tails and  2 tails / one heads
So probability of 0.5 to have at most one tails

So, P(at most 1 tails | there is both tails and heads)=0.5

If you know that there is not one tail and one head, then, the only possibility is 3 tails or 3 heads and they are equi-probable (by symmetry)

So in that case too 
P(at most 1 tails | there is not both tails and heads)=0.5

So your events are independent as the probability of one does not depend on the realization of the other